# How to get matplotlib text(x, y, "String", bbox=...) axis coordinates

Tags: python, matplotlib

For example, I can create a text with rounded box using

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,1)
obj = ax.text(0.2, 0.6, "something", bbox = dict(boxstyle = 'round'))
```

Now I would like to get the rounded box corner points in the plot. I have tried using

`obj.clipbox.corners()`

But it does not return the points of the plot, it does not match the points in the plot. Also have tried using

`obj.clipbox.transformed(...)`

still not work. May I ask for help on this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First note that `clipbox` is the box by which the artist is clipped. This is usually the axes bounding box. It has hence nothing to do with the box around the text.

Now you may get the box around the text via

```
obj = ax.text(...)
box = obj.get_bbox_patch()
```

The problem is that size and position of the box around the text is only determined once the text is actually drawn. Before that, it does not know where it is.

So first you need to draw the canvas. This updates the coordinates of the box. Then you can get the window extent of the box via `box.get_window_extent()`. This would give the coordinates in display space (pixels of the figure) so you need to convert them back to data coordinates.

```
fig.canvas.draw()
coords = ax.transData.inverted().transform(box.get_window_extent())
print(coords)
```

this prints

```
[[ 0.19159946  0.58060967]
 [ 0.35633401  0.64103535]]
```

which are the data coordinates of the box around the text (first row lower left corner, second row upper right corner).

Comment: Thanks. So you mean before showing the plot, the coordinates of all boxes will always be the same (default value) ?

Comment: Yes without drawing the canvas, the box will just be from 0 to 1 in arbitrary coordinates, `Bbox(x0=0.0, y0=0.0, x1=1.0, y1=1.0)`.

Comment: When i tried, I have a box that spans with a corner at point x = 1.5, but neither of the printed coordinates shows a number near 1.5

Comment: Also, the method `.overlaps` does not seem to work. It always return a `True`, even when two boxes are not overlap.

Comment: I think because I had put `ax.set_xlim(...)` AFTER the canvas drawing. When I put it before, it works.

Comment: Sure. If the limits change after drawing, the coordinates will all be wrong again.